# mysql new user access denied to database

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql-5.6

Created a new user. Can't access the database.
I've tried everything I can find or think of.
From Workbench on localhost

```
SELECT user, host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
```

shows

```
# user  host    plugin
root    localhost   mysql_native_password
root    127.0.0.1   mysql_native_password
root    ::1 mysql_native_password
newuser localhost   mysql_native_password
```

I grant all privileges on all tables to the new user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

shows

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*...'
```

As root, I can

```
use db;
```

But that fails as newuser with
Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'newuser'@'localhost' to database 'db'

I simplified the password to just letters and numbers. That did help. Now I can log in to workbench. Still can't access the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_upgrade was the primary answer.
Also, I had one connection using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.